# Does move priority come first when deciding option card play?

Tags: robo-rally

If you started in Dock 1, but my move has higher priority than yours, and my option cards involve my movement while your option card involves your movement, does the higher movement priority allow me to execute my option first (then allow you to take your move and then execute your option), or does the ruling on page 8 on resolving option card priority imply that the docking bay priority rules overtop of each 'complete registers' or 'robots move' segment (and in this case the dock 1 player, you, goes first)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the option card priority rules only apply when decisions about option cards would otherwise be made at the same time, for example, if you're both firing lasers and deciding whether to use options. But if you're moving, you already know who moves first, and you decide whether to use the option card as you move, so the option card priority rules never come into play.